# include in-app-purchases in a ios paid aplication

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to publish a iOS paid app, that includes a in app purchases module.

Is possible to include a in app purchases module in a iOS application for payment?

Answer (score 0):

First Google search result (https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/)

> In-App Purchase lets you sell a variety of items directly within your free or paid app